# get multiple variables with url

Tags: php

i am triying to acess multiple variables from another skript. i am doing it with this  method because include dont work for me and cant figure out why:

skript 1

```
$QT = $_POST["QT"];
  header("location: ../main/Skript2.php/?number=$QT");
```

skript2

```
<?php
$QT = $_GET['number'];
echo $QT;
?>
```

thanks to @rauwitt

just with one variable its working great, but is there a way to store with the same method multiple in the url?

i tried it like this but it doesnt work

```
header("location: ../main/ProcessOrder.php/?number=$QT/url=$var2");
```

thanklss

Comment: Multiple URL parameters are separated with `&`. `?number=$QT&url=$var`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
header("location: ../main/ProcessOrder.php?number=$QT&url=$var2");
```

Comment: A good answer should not just throw a line of code at your head, but _explain_ what is shown.

Comment: yes that was working thankss